# Can't change innerHtml neither with plain JavaScript not with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is source code of the simple page:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
    <script src="jquery-1.4.2.js" type=text/javascript></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="divText">Original</div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        var vText = document.getElementById('divText');
        vText.innerText = 'Changed';
        alert(vText.innerHTML);
        $('divText').text = 'Changed with jQuery';
        alert(vText.innerHTML);
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

"jquery-1.4.2.js" file is in the same folder.

Both alerts display "original" text, text in browser also "Original"...

What is wrong with my code? Any thoughts are welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you pointed out in the title you'll be wanting to change the inner html. You'll also need the `$('#divText')` selector to get to the div with jQuery.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
    <script src="jquery-1.4.2.js" type=text/javascript></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="divText">Original</div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        var vText = document.getElementById('divText');
        vText.innerHTML = 'Changed';
        alert(vText.innerHTML);
        alert($('#divText'));
        $('#divText').html('Changed with jQuery');
        alert(vText.innerHTML);
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

**1**. A [quick google](http://www.google.com/search?q=jquery+text) ( took me 2 seconds ) reveals text is a **function**, not a property. Use it like `.text('lol')` as the example directly from the API.

http://api.jquery.com/text/

**2**. `innerText` isn't available in every browser/DOM property.

Comment: 1. Agree, also saw that but 'lost'... 2. Yup, the code is on my work and it didn't work in Chrome, but worked in FF (or vice versa)